# Effect of escaping text. How to reverse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After the first mouse over this text, it should move by 200px to the right, after another mouse over the text returns to its original place (moves by 200px to the left)

How to do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. But first search for `move mouseover OR hover jquery` - I found 4 relevant links in 2 minutes

Comment: The attached link does not explain my question. I would like to stay at same poistion my text after mouseout and it should back when I will do next mouseover.

Comment: Show code you have so far with image of expected result